# Nginx Proxy Pass and remove .php extension from URL

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to `Proxy Pass` `/do/uploads.php?id=xxx` to `/do/upload?id=xxx` in Nginx

Here is my try

```
location /do {
    rewrite /do/uploads\.php /do/uploads$1 break;
    proxy_pass          http://domain/do;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Here it is:

```
location = /do/uploads.php {
    proxy_pass          http://domain/switch/do;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```